# Separate and store values of an array with the same values and different values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have stored data in array contains id that I need to separate with the same id and different id then store it to different array.

I tried to use for loop but it seems that my logic wasn't correct.

This is how I store data in an array:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($supplier_id); $i++){
                $req_arr[$i] = array(
                    'supplier_id' => $supplier_id[$i],
                    'itemloc_id'  => $itemloc_id[$i],
                    'item_id'     => $item_id[$i],
                    'item_qty'    => $item_qty[$i],
                    'item_price'  => $item_price[$i],
                    'uomid'       => $uomid[$i],
                    'item_total_price' => $item_total_price[$i]
                );

            }
```

`$req_arr` contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [supplier_id] => 86
            [itemloc_id] => 8
            [item_id] => 112
            [item_qty] => 5
            [item_price] => 100
            [uomid] => 54
            [item_total_price] => 500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [supplier_id] => 86
            [itemloc_id] => 8
            [item_id] => D111
            [item_qty] => 5
            [item_price] => 100
            [uomid] => 54
            [item_total_price] => 500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [supplier_id] => 80
            [itemloc_id] => 8
            [item_id] => CK091
            [item_qty] => 5
            [item_price] => 100
            [uomid] => 54
            [item_total_price] => 500
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [supplier_id] => 92
            [itemloc_id] => 8
            [item_id] => SS1
            [item_qty] => 5
            [item_price] => 100
            [uomid] => 54
            [item_total_price] => 500
        )

)
```

I want to separate the values of supplier_id inside an array with same and different value in different variable.

My expected results are:

```
$same_value = [0] => Array
        (
            [supplier_id] => 86
            [itemloc_id] => 8
            [item_id] => 112
            [item_qty] => 5
            [item_price] => 100
            [uomid] => 54
            [item_total_price] => 500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [supplier_id] => 86
            [itemloc_id] => 8
            [item_id] => D111
            [item_qty] => 5
            [item_price] => 100
            [uomid] => 54
            [item_total_price] => 500
        )



$diff_value = [2] => Array
        (
            [supplier_id] => 80
            [itemloc_id] => 8
            [item_id] => CK091
            [item_qty] => 5
            [item_price] => 100
            [uomid] => 54
            [item_total_price] => 500
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [supplier_id] => 92
            [itemloc_id] => 8
            [item_id] => SS1
            [item_qty] => 5
            [item_price] => 100
            [uomid] => 54
            [item_total_price] => 500
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to determine first which ids or array groups have more than counts of two.

So you can apply `array_column` initially to get all the `supplier_id`s, the just simply use `array_count_values` to get their count on each batch.

```
$id_count = array_count_values(array_column($req_arr, 'supplier_id'));
```

So this should yield the following:

```
Array
(
    [86] => 2
    [80] => 1
    [92] => 1
)
```

Now you have a clear understanding of the separation for pushing which groups you need to. Just apply a simple `if` block to separate them:

```
$same = $diff = [];
$id_count = array_count_values(array_column($req_arr, 'supplier_id'));
foreach ($req_arr as $values) {
    if (!empty($id_count[$values['supplier_id']]) && $id_count[$values['supplier_id']] > 1) {
        // push to same
        $same[] = $values;
    } else {
        // push to diff
        $diff[] = $values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Commended bro! Thanks for this new knowledge.